# Characteristic function of logarithm of random variable

Tags: probability-theory, fourier-analysis, logarithms, characteristic-functions

If I know the characteristic function $\phi_X(t)$ of a random variable $X>0$, how can I write the characteristic function $\phi_Y(t)$ of $Y=\log(X)$?

I know that $\phi_X(t)=E[e^{itX}]$ and $\phi_Y(t)=E[e^{it\log(X)}]$. But I can't derive one from the other. Any idea? I would like to use $\phi_X(t)$ to calculate the second moments $X$.

Comment: Have you tried to apply the definition? You have more chance of getting answers here if you show us some of your effort, or some context or motivation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question comes up in various guises: knowing the Fourier transform of $f$ (in your case, the probability density function of $X$), can we find the Fourier transform of another related function (in your case, the p.d.f. of $\log X$)? Unfortunately, nonlinear transformations completely mess up the picture of the Fourier transform. All one can do is to invert the Fourier transform, apply the desired nonlinear transformation, and take the Fourier transform of that.

Comment: If your pointwise nonlinearity has a nice Taylor expansion, you can directly view this as a sum over iterated convolutions in the Fourier domain. This is only really useful when your nonlinearity is low-order (e.g. just x²) and/or the convolutions have an obvious closed form for all terms in the series you care about. But, its no better than inverting the FT, anyway. I've never really used this, but it may let you skip some steps. Especially if your FT comes from a family of fns closed under convolution.

Answer (score 1):

We need to compute the log-characteristic function that is the characteristic of $Y=\ln\left(X\right)$. So, we need to express the characteristic function of $Y$ in terms of values $X$: $$E\left(\exp\left(ikY\right)\right)=\int_{l_{y}}^{u_{y}}\exp\left(iky\right)f_{Y}\left(y\right)dy$$
As $y=\ln\left(x\right)$, we have $dy=\frac{dx}{x}$ and so :
$$E\left(\exp\left(ikY\right)\right)=\int_{\exp\left(l_{y}\right)}^{\exp\left(u_{y}\right)}\exp\left(ik\ln\left(x\right)\right)f_{Y}\left(\ln\left(x\right)\right)\frac{dx}{x}$$
We need to express the density $f_{Y}$ of $Y$ in terms of the density $f_{X}$ of $X$. As $Y=g\left(X\right)=\ln(X)$, because the probabilities are invariant by change of variables, the transformation is strictly monotone and derivable in all the domain of X so that:
$$f_{Y}\left(y\right)=\left|\frac{1}{g'\left(g^{-1}\left(y\right)\right)}\right|.f_{X}\left(g^{-1}\left(y\right)\right)$$
$$\Leftrightarrow f_{Y}\left(y\right)=\exp\left(y\right).f_{X}\left(\exp\left(y\right)\right)=x.f_{X}\left(x\right)$$
In the end, the log characteristic function equals:
$$E\left(\exp\left(ikY\right)\right)=\int_{\exp\left(l_{y}\right)}^{\exp\left(u_{y}\right)}\exp\left(ik\ln\left(x\right)\right)x.f_{X}\left(x\right)\frac{dx}{x}$$
$$\Leftrightarrow E\left(\exp\left(ikY\right)\right)=\int_{\exp\left(l_{y}\right)}^{\exp\left(u_{y}\right)}\exp\left(ik\ln\left(x\right)\right)f_{X}\left(x\right)dx$$
Q.E.D.

Comment: I believe that the bounds of integration are incorrect. Shouldn't they be e^{l_y} and e^{l_u}, rather than ln(l_y) and ln(l_u)?

Comment: Right ! Except that error (now corrected), my answer is correct